# Display a tooltip on iPhone above the user click location

Tags: ios, iphone, tooltip

In android apps, it's very easy to show a tooltip (they call that a *Toast*). But I can't find an easy way to do the same in iOS apps.
I saw several things about this question, but my goal is to publish my app on the app store, so I want to use a proper way to do these tooltips...

Then, is there any way to do a tooltip according to Apple philosophy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Android Toast equivalent built in. Many people use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

Comment: Yes, but this is very similar to Android. So is there any risk for my application could be rejected by Apple when I'll try to publish it to the App Store ?

Comment: No, not for using a 3rd party library with an iOS app. It is a very common practice.

Comment: Ok, I trust you ! Thanks